# mod_rewrite will not rewrite, no errors in logs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite

```
http://localhost/pex/index.php?p=login
```

to

```
http://localhost/pex/login
```

If the re get is set

```
http://localhost/pex/index.php?p=login&re=users
```

to

```
http://localhost/pex/login/re/users
```

I used http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ which suggested:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pex/([^/]*)/re/([^/]*)$ /pex/index.php?p=$1&re=$2 [L]
```

This did not work on WAMP and generated no errors with LogLevel = debug.

Note that /pex/ is only a temporary folder, it will eventually be in the root dir.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/path/to/site">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

In .htaccess add and this line in first line:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

Comment: Still nothing. `Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pex/([^/]*)/re/([^/]*)$ /pex/index.php?p=$1&re=$2 [L]`

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/
 <Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
 AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`  This is my httpd.conf

Comment: I've tried both local system and server hosting many sites which have working mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess